# Find the mean and variance of $Z = \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$

Tags: probability

The question states

> Find the mean and variance of $Z = \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ given that x and y are uniformly distributed and independent

As I go through this, my first instinct is to do it by definition, that is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2} * \sqrt{X^2+ Y^2} dx dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty X^2 + Y^2 dxdy$

However, at this point, I'm not sure what the way forward is? Do I convert X and Y to their distributions such as $\frac{1}{a-b}$?

Thank you so much in advanced for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Recall that the density of the uniform is $1$ on $[0,1]$ and zero elsewhere. The second moment is easy to compute: $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x^2+y^2) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy} = \frac{2}{3}$. The mean is a bit hairy...

Answer (score 1):

For continuous random variables $W_1, W_2$ with joint density $f$, and a (nice-enough) function $g$, you can find the expectation as
$$
\mathbb{E}[g(W_1, W_2)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(w,w') \,f(w,w')\,dw\,dw'
$$
So, applying this to one of the calculations for your example,
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}\right)^2\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 \, f(x,y) \,dx\,dy
$$
where $f$ is the joint density of $X$ and $Y$, but since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $f(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ ...

Answer (score 1):

The first moment (mean) is easy to calculate via doing the integral $E[\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}] = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} f_X(x) f_Y(y) dx dy$. Note that $f_X(x) f_Y(y)$ is only non-zero on some rectangle (where it is constant), and you can easily calculate this integral out. If $X \sim$ Uniform(a,b) and $Y \sim $ Uniform(c,d), the mean is given by the integral is just $\int_a^b \int_c^d \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \frac{1}{(d-c)^2} dx dy$.

As for calculating out the second moment, $E[(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})^2] = E[X^2+Y^2] = E[X^2]+E[Y^2]$. The second moment of a uniform distribution are well known (for $Z \sim $Uniform(a,b) distribution, $E[Z^2]=\frac{1}{12} (b-a)^2 + \left( \frac{b-a}{2} \right)^2$). Then, note that the variance is $E[(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})^2]$ minus the mean squared.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you got to the result $E[Z^2]=\frac{1}{12} (b-a)^2 + \left( \frac{b-a}{2} \right)^2$? Like for example where did the $\frac{1}{12}$ come from?

Comment: Its just using $var(Z) = E[Z^2] - E[Z]^2$. For $Z \sim$ Uniform(a,b), $var(Z) = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$ and $E[Z] = \frac{b-a}{2}$ (you can look these up in a table, or just do the integral for $E[Z^2] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} z^2 f_Z(z) dz = \int_a^b z^2 \frac{1}{b-a} dz$.

Comment: How would you actually compute the integral for the mean? Polar coordinates?

Comment: Knowing the derivative of $\sinh^{-1}$, I suppose.

Comment: When you say $var(Z) = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$ that is for Z, a uniformly distributed random variable. The same could be said of $var(x)$ or $var(y)$?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are uniform random variables, you can substitute their parameters into that expression to get their variances and second moments.